# How to find hashed value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using `mongoose` library in nodeJS. I want to pass the password in `plaintext`, and match it's hashed value, to find an element in the collection.

For example, in `mysql`, I can use:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE MD5(PASSWORD) = "HASHED_PASSWORD";
```

`mysql` has a `MD5()` function.

Does mongoDB has anything similar ?

**I know passwords should be hashed before storing, but just wanted to know if this is possible in MongoDB or not**

Comment: how about to make a helper function to convert plaintext to hashed then find in mongo ?

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam: in this case, mongodb stores plaintext passwords, not hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Currently as of MongoDB 3.6.1, there is no built-in hash function like you described. In most cases, hash functions are better implemented in your application.

Consider the scenario you posted above. MD5 is known to be weak. If your application relies on the database to calculate this hash, now you're faced with some issues:

1. A big change in the database would be required to migrate all weak hashes to new hashes. Otherwise you're facing the issue of having to keep different versions of your schema, which may not be ideal.
2. You cannot simply replace the `hash()` function in the database with a stronger one and keep the name of the function the same, since this will create incompatibilities with already stored hashes.

If you keep the hash function in your application, you can still use the same database and data structure. You can store hashes with the new algorithm differently (e.g. with a sub-document detailing the algorithm used and the hash string, instead of a single string), and let the application detect which algorithm to use.